# Xcode not found in the PATH and expo cannot run iOS simulator

Tags: node.js, xcode, shell, path, expo

I messed up my PATH and expo no longer recognises Xcode being installed. I know that it is because of the PATH and I tried most of the suggestions here on Stack and the problem got worse.

Firstly, every time I open a terminal I am prompted with these messages:

```
Last login: Wed Feb 15 19:25:08 on ttys001
/etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:104: command not found: mkdir
```

When I write `which expo` I am prompted with `/opt/homebrew/bin/expo`.

When I write `which Xcode` I am prompted with `xcode not found`. :(

When I type `echo $PATH` I am prompted with all this:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew";
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
```

As the initial problem was with (AWS) `amplify pull` command not being recognised, I followed the steps in [this thread](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) to write on the `.zprofile`  so I typed :

```
2. vim .zprofile
3. Press i, then paste this line
export PATH="$HOME/.amplify/bin:$PATH" 
4. Press Esc and :wq to save this file
```

Then I changed stuff again following [this thread](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and I understand now how to add `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/` but it disappears when I close the terminal.

Also, neither `vim` nor `ls` are recognised commands.

Question 1:
Is there a way to restore my system variables and PATH to a default?

Question 2:
How could I change my path for expo to see the application installed and run the simulator?

Question 3:
How do I make it permanent/save it?

I would be forever grateful for any support, because there has been 2 days of frustration now.. :((

Please help!